# C - strcpy with malloc size less than argument's size

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

```
char* init_array()
{
    const int size = 5;
    char *p = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p, "Hello, world! How are you?");

    return p;
}
```

with size = 5, malloc should get 5 free chars from memory, but given string does not fit into 5 chars, yet it works.

My question is why? First I thought the result would get truncated but p is the fully string, not just "Hello" or "Hell\0"

I'm using GCC on Linux. Is it related to the compiler or it is standard stuff?

Comment: how do you know it works? what you observe is "undefined behaviour". You know your code is faulty, but these faults don't always lead to failures or crashes, in fact, anything might happen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Standard warning: [Do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1151654)

Comment: Simply by printing the return pointer, using printf("%s", init_array());

Comment: @ usrc then, read here and read right. see the link @Eregrith added.

Comment: When programs fail, they don't do so in a deterministic, consistent or predictable manner.

Comment: This is called **undefined behaviour**. Think about the implications of the word **undefined**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called undefined behavior, since it's undefined sometimes it works. Yes you can write past a memory block in c, but that's illegal because it invokes undefined behavior, the behavior is therefore not predictable and your program might or might not work.

What you expect from `strcpy()` doesn't happen because `strcpy()` copies as many characters as it finds before the `'\0'` terminating byte, it doesn't care if the destination buffer is large enough, that's something you must be responsible about.

If you want to copy an exact number of bytes (*let's say 5*) you can use

```
memcpy(p, "Hello, this string is very large but it doesn't matter", 5);
```

but beware that `p` is not a valid string after that, because it has no terminating `'\0'`.

You also have 2 other common bad practice that new c programmers do

1. You don't need to cast the return value from `malloc()`.
2. You don't need to use `sizeof(char)` because it's 1 by definition.

So,

```
p = malloc(size);
```

should be enough to allocate space for a `size - 1` characters string.

Comment: I hereby suggest to replace `mistake` with `bad practice`. Would you mind? :-)

Comment: @NatashaDutta It's a lot better than the footnote...

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/buffer_overflow)

In short, you write to invalid memory addresses invoking [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it worked but in fact your code invokes undefined behavior. You are writing data to unallocated memory location.

You should note that in

```
strcpy(str1, str2);
```

`strcpy` has no way to check whether the string pointed to by `str2` will fit into the character array `str1`. In your case it will continue to copy the characters from `"Hello, world! How are you?` to past the array `p` points to.